# Format text in a richtextbox that falls between 2 chosen characters

Tags: c#, string, winforms, richtextbox

I need to format text as it is typed into a rich text box. So for example..

text text ( text text text) text text text.

the text in brackets with change to the specified font and colour as they are being typed and when the bracket is closed, any following text will go back to 'using' the rich text boxes default font/colour.

What I have so far...

```
private void FormatMiddleText (string start, string end, Font font, Color color)    
{
    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
    this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = font;
}
```

Usage...

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
Font font = new Font(
   fontFamily,
   16,
   FontStyle.Bold,
   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


FormatMiddleText("(",")", Color.Red,  font)
```

Can't work out how to make the `RichTextBox` selection the text that is between the start and end string.

Comment: You forget to select the text before applying format.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to keep track of the selected text. The beginning and the end. so this has to go into your `FormatMiddleText` method and since it should be an index `int` would be the preferable type:

```
private void FormatMiddleText(int start, int end, Font font, Color color)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = end;

    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
    this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = font;
    // reset the selection start so you can keep typing at the right hand side
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
}
```

Now you need to keep track of the typing. You need a startIndex and a count how far the text goes which has to be formatted. Also a flag would be good to know whether you apply your "cool" format or the boring default one

```
int startIndex = 0;
int charCount = 0;
bool startFormatting = false;
```

Now you can use the `TextChanged` event to handle the formatting as the user types in the text:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Last() == '(')
    {
        // remember the start index
        startIndex = richTextBox1.Text.Length-1; // -1 will take the "(" also to be formatted
        startFormatting = true; // now you can start formatting with the cool font
    }

    if (richTextBox1.Text.Last() == ')')
    {
        MessageBox.Show("found end ");
        startIndex = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
        startFormatting = false;   // now you can proceed to format with boring default font             
    }

    charCount++;

    if (startFormatting)
    {
        FormatMiddleText(startIndex, charCount, font, Color.Red);
    }
    else
    {
        FormatMiddleText(startIndex, charCount, DefaultFont, Color.Black);
    }
}
```

I haven't found a way to just reset the font and keep writing in default without constant formatting. Because setting the `richTextBox1.Font = DefaultFont;` will reset the format between the parentheses. So I chose to keep formatting. If you find a way, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
    private void rtb_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D0 && e.Shift)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    private void rtb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '(')
        {
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

You can use `SelectionFont` instead of `SelectionColor` to provide more complex font properties. Also, you can replace the parentheses with any opening and closing characters to get the same effect. Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies. txtResponse was supposed to be the name of your RichTextBox. I have edited the answer accordingly.